# Strip HTML when pasting into single-line text field

Tags: experience-editor

If someone copies HTML from another site (like a title) and pastes it into a single-line text field, is there any way to automatically strip the HTML out? I know with rich text fields there are paste options to do this if you want, but with single-line text it sometimes throws one of those "an error occurred" messages in experience editor (logs come back with "After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: O") and sometimes it just shows the raw HTML instead. Thanks.

Comment: Not prepared to use this as an answer just yet, but you could use the item:saving event to wire up logic that would strip out HTML out of a field upon saving.

Comment: Only catch to that is sometimes the process is creating that "error occurred" on save, so it'd never hit item:saving. If it got past that it could work, but this seems more like something someone should really just paste it into a text editor first. Or just make the fields rich text and they deal with the consequences. :)

Comment: Yeah, my feeling is that you would either paste to notepad first or strip on save/saving.

Comment: some js to listen on single line text change?

Comment: Or more specifically - onpaste. Some info from w3s - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onpaste.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want to directly paste the copied contents in experience editor, unlike RichText Field which provides dialog-popup.

In your layout, any master rendering page, or any global javascript, try to add this javascript.

```js
<script>
    document.addEventListener('paste', function (e) {
        var content = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
        document.execCommand('insertText', false, content);
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Refresh the page with disabled cache status in browser and test

Comment: I have yet to try this answer for myself, but this is a unique solution that I've not seen yet. Nice answer.

Comment: I have tested this method in 8.2 and it seems very promising.  It does not strip line-breaks, it will add `<br/>` appropriately.  All other inline scripts are removed properly.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered hooking into `item:saving` Sitecore event? You can retrieve an item being saved and sanitize its fields:

```cs
public void OnItemSaving(object sender, System.EventArgs args)
{
    Item item = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) as Item;
    Error.AssertNotNull(item, "No item in parameters");
    //modify item fields as required
}
```

More info in John West's post: https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/repost-intercepting-item-updates-with-sitecore